# SoX (Sound eXchange) Dying on some MP3 Files

Tags: encoding, mp3, mp4, sox

I've been using sox from the command line to run an audio conversion web tool. It's working pretty well. I compiled it with MP3 support (which does work) and have also installed ffmpeg to handle m4a files.

My problem is that some mp3's, which come in with a mime-type of audio/mpeg (the mime-type for mp3 files), actually have the audio encoded using mp4. They are indistinguishable from normal mp3's in every way I've been able to test, and neither sox nor ffmpeg seem to know what to do with them.

I've spent approximately 2 weeks researching this issue, and come across many articles that deal with mp4's, mp3's and sox, but none that deal with mp3's that have an mp4 encoding (which seem to be fairly common from what I'm seeing).

I'm not even sure where to look at this point. Surely this is a problem that someone has encountered before?

Answer (score 1):

MP4 is not an encoding, but a container format that may contain audio or video with varying encodings, including AAC or ALAC. FFmpeg should be able to read it and most of the encodings. What does `ffprobe your_file` say?